# How to determine an index only scan from Explain output in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I did goolge this for a long time, there are many similar questions and articles. But no one really mentions how I should determine if the query is an index only scan from Explain output. I am new to Explain analyzer. Is there any easy way so that I can be sure the query is not accessing the heap at all?

There are many Scan types. I don't know which scan types mean accessing heap and which scan types mean not accessing the heap (thus index-only).

Comment: The output would include `Index Scan using <index> on <table>`. With a line saying what the index condition was.

Comment: @JSpratt thanks for the reply, but my question is how to determine the query is index-only scan. That means to determine the query is not accessing the heap at all. One index scan does not mean all scans are using index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index-only scans are labeled that way in explain output.

For example:

```
Aggregate  (cost=156.210..156.220 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.176..2.176 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using quebec on papa  (cost=0.280..149.360 rows=2739 width=27) (actual time=0.120..0.960 rows=2739 loops=1)
```

Comment: Will "index only scan" always have the keyword `Index Only Scan`? Some articles show some index-only-scan Explain output examples which do not have this keyword. Let me google more on this to clarify. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you are right. I have upvoted your answer and marked it as the accepted answer too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sgon00: yes an index only scan will always be shown as `Index Only Scan`, a regular index access (reading both index and the table) is shown as `Index Scan`. See [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/postgresql/operations)  - which really should be part of the Postgres manual ;)